# Plot a Cell Array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I am attempting to plot a cell array of data, where I solve for a radius 'ry' based on a given theta 't'. I am using a for loop to store the data in this cell array.

```
for t = 0:pi/100:2*pi
    cell(n,1) = t;
    cell(n,2) = (1/4*pi)*((K1c/Sys)^2)*(1+cos(t)+(3/2)*(sin(t/2)^2));
    n=n+1; 
end;
```

Where K1c = 45 and Sys = 40. My issue is attempting to plot this cell.

Obviously, it is not as simple as using plot(cell), or using plot(cell(n,1),cell(n,2)). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks guys,

Cody

Comment: can you convert the cell array to a numerical array? use function cell2mat http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html and plot the matrix.

Comment: and do you have to use cell array for this?

Comment: You neither need cell nor for loops. Its a 3 liner code including "plotting". Here's a hint... define t as `0:pi/100:2*pi` and proceed. Just use simple variables to store output.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using a cell array. The way you store your data is a normal matrix.
The plot command is then

```
plot(cell(:, 1), cell(:, 2))
```

If you wanted to store your data in a cell you'd have to reassign your matrix cell to some other variable (as cell is a reserved expression in matlab)

```
a = cell;
clear cell;
b = cell(1, 2) %Create 1x2 cell
b{1} = a(:, 1);
b{2} = a(:, 2);
plot(b{1}, b{2});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make it so complicated. Matlab is designed to easily handle whole vectors and matrices of data at once, without the need for loops.

```
t = 0: pi/100: 2*pi;
y = (pi/4) * (45/40)^2 * (1 + cos(t) + 3/2 * sin(t/2).^2);
plot(t, y)
```

Which results in

[image]